# Hive Jdbc is very slow

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, jdbctemplate

Following this [guide](https://github.com/mouryar/spring_hive_jdbc_template), I connect to hive using jdbctemplate autheticated by kerberos. I am new to hive.

After getting connection, I try to execute some sql, but it is very slow to get all results.

```java
while (resultSet.next()) {
   // process each row
}
```

And I can see a lot of logs like below for each row got from resultSet:

```bash
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveQueryResultSet - Fetched row string:
org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - writing data length: 100
org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport - CLIENT reading data length: 256
```

It seems that slowness is due to limit of transport size(256 bytes I guess in this case). If so, how can I increase the size?